# Django changes field types on query results (!)

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have the following model

```
class MonitorData(models.Model):
  [... other stuff]
  starttime = models.CharField(max_length=64, db_column='spurlStartTime', blank=True)
```

So, the starttime is a char field (in the database, it represents a datetime column)

Now, here's what I am doing:

```
oo=models.MonitorData.objects.all()
print oo[0].starttime
print type(oo[0].starttime)
```

And here's what I am getting:

```
00:35:59
<type 'datetime.time'>
```

For my own reasons (don't want to discuss them) I want to read it as a varchar and then parse it myself. But django is NOT allowing me to do that because, for reasons unknown to me, it converts that to a datetime !!!

Can anybody explain to me why django has that behaviour and how can I get my precious strings back ? Is there a way to force django cast this value as string ?

ps: I know how to use str() so pls don't answer me that

Comment: I'm actually a little surprised this works remotely at all, but since the field is a DATETIME, Django is going to treat it as a datetime.

Comment: I'm assuming the `oo[0].spurlstarttime` is a typo and should be `oo[0].starttime`?

Comment: Yes it is starttime - fixed it

Comment: Yes, I know it is a datetime but i can't understand why i can't treat it as a string if i want to. isn't there a way to do that ?

Comment: Because it's *not* a string. If Django actually treated as a string, you'd get an `IntegrityError`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django hasn't done anything to it. The DBAPI adapter sees that it's a DATETIME and therefore returns a datetime. And there's nothing in `CharField` that forces a datetime to text.

Comment: So what could I do if I wanted to do that (force date time to text)? Subclass CharField ?

Comment: Sure. But what you should really do is make it a VARCHAR in the database.

Answer (score 0):

I think,
Instead of saving the value in the datetime format. Try to save it in the isoformat. You can convert easily.